# ASP.NET MVC model bind ID mismatch

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View in MVC 2 where I edit a "Page". A Page has a Name, Title and Content. Content is of type EditableContent, which has Width, CssClass and Columns. Columns is a List.

When I do this in the view:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
```

It outputs the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="About Page" name="Name" id="Name">
```

And when I post to the Edit action in ContentController:

```
/// <summary>
/// Edits the specified form.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item">The content page.</param>
/// <returns>ActionResult for edit</returns>
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Page item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }

    return View(item);
}
```

It cannot bind the Name property to item.Name. Looking up the values in Request.Form, I see the Name parameter.

If I render the textbox manually, using this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("item.Name", Model.Name)%>
```

The value is binded perfectly to the Page instance in the controller action.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your action method parameter is named *item*, the DefaultModelBinder will look for *item.name*, *item.title*, *item.content.width*, etc.  If it can't find any *item.** in the request, it will ignore the *item* prefix and fall back to the empty prefix, looking just for *name*, *title*, *content.width*, etc.

Chances are something else in the request is called *item* (or *item.**), which is causing this fallback logic not to occur.  If you want to force the fallback logic, attribute the parameter with [Bind(Prefix = "")], which says "yeah, I know this parameter was named item, but pretend its name is actually ''."

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, have you tried entering the full namespace for your Page parameter in your Action? There may be a naming conflict.

Comment: I have now. That doesn't help. I'm wondering if I should use the CastleBinder in MvcContrib.

Comment: try using <input type="text" value="About Page" name="item" id="item"> in the view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use prefixes for model names. This will isolates input for different models.
Example of action

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="Page")]Page item)
```

{...}

when rendering input

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Page.Name", Model.Name)%>
```

Sorry, don't now how to do this using helper with lambda expression.